# "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement"

Tags: php, javascript, append

Im trying to write code which will add javascript in a variable. Everything is going find until i get the error `"SyntaxError: missing ; before statement"` ... I have found out that if i remove a line then it works (i will put // ---- on that line). Please can someone help?

```
$this->paint_javascript_function_text .= '
    function image_'.$this->archive_id.'_rollover (){
        document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = "'.$this->archive_name.'<br />'.$this->archive_dimensions.' - Price &#163;'.$this->archive_price.' inc Packaging";
    }
    function image_'.$this->archive_id.'_fullsize (){
        document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML = ';
        $this->paint_javascript_function_text .= "'";

        $this->paint_javascript_function_text .= '<table width="100%" height="400"border="0" align="center"><tr><td align="right" valign="middle">';
        if($this->archive_id == 1) {
            $this->paint_javascript_function_text .= '<img src="images/paint_gallery/prev_faded.png" border="0" class="paint_nav" />';
        }
        else
        {
            $prev = $this->archive_id - 1;
            $this->paint_javascript_function_text .= '<a href="#"><img src="images/paint_gallery/prev.png" border="0" class="paint_nav" onclick="javascript:image_'.$prev.'_fullsize();" /></a>';
        }

        $this->paint_javascript_function_text .= '</td><td width="400px" height="523px" align="center" valign="middle">'.$newimage.'<br /><a href="#" class="paint_link" onclick="javascript:return_to_small_images();">Back to Gallery</a></td><td align="left" valign="middle">';
        if($total_num == $this->archive_id){
            $this->paint_javascript_function_text .= '<img src="images/paint_gallery/next_faded.png" border="0" class="paint_nav" />';
        }
        else
        {
            $next = $this->archive_id + 1;
            $this->paint_javascript_function_text .= '<a href="#"><img src="images/paint_gallery/next.png" border="0" onclick="javascript:image_'.$next.'_fullsize();" class="paint_nav" /></a>';
        }

        $this->paint_javascript_function_text .= '</td></tr></table>';

        // ---- $this->paint_javascript_function_text .= '<center><span class="paintings_title">'.$this->archive_name.' - '.$this->archive_dimensions.' - '.$this->archive_price.' inc P&P</span><br /><a href="basket.php?addprint='.$this->archive_id.'"><img src="images/shop/basket_button.png" border="0" /></a></center>';
        $this->paint_javascript_function_text .= "';
            ";
        $this->paint_javascript_function_text .= '
            $("#main_content").hide();
            $("#gallery").show();
            $("#paint_nav").hide();
    }';
```

HTML Output:

```
function image_4_fullsize (){
    document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML = '<table width="100%" height="400" border="0" align="center"><tr><td align="right" valign="middle"><a href="#"><img src="images/paint_gallery/prev.png" border="0" class="paint_nav" onclick="javascript:image_3_fullsize();" /></a></td><td width="400px" height="523px" align="center" valign="middle"><img src="images/print_gallery/Countrymans Kitchen.jpg" /><br /><a href="#" class="paint_link" onclick="javascript:return_to_small_images();">Back to Gallery</a></td><td align="left" valign="middle"><a href="#"><img src="images/paint_gallery/next.png" border="0" onclick="javascript:image_5_fullsize();" class="paint_nav" /></a></td></tr></table><center><span class="paintings_title">Countryman's Kitchen -  -  inc P&P</span><br /><a href="basket.php?addprint=4"><img src="images/shop/basket_button.png" border="0" /></a></center>';

    $("#main_content").hide();
    $("#gallery").show();
    $("#paint_nav").hide();
}
```

Comment: Use 'json_encode` instead

Comment: Will that line append a `'` somewhere? It would be nice if you could also put the generated HTML on which the browser points out the error.

Comment: See that line `<span class="paintings_title">Countryman's Kitchen -  -  `, `$this->archive_name` contains a single quote, as i said, better way is using `json_encode` to set the `innerHTML` data

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**
Change below line

`$this->archive_name` contains a single quote, so you need to escape that first with `json_encode`

```
$this->paint_javascript_function_text .= 'function image_'.$this->archive_id.'_rollover () {
  document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = '.json_encode( $this->archive_name.'<br />'.$this->archive_dimensions.' - Price &#163;'.$this->archive_price.' inc Packagin' ).';
}
function image_'.$this->archive_id.'_fullsize() {
  document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML = ';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating using shorthand ".="
And then concatenating "the normal way".

try this way:

```
 $this->paint_javascript_function_text = $this->paint_javascript_function_text . '<center><span class="paintings_title">'.$this->archive_name.' - '.$this->archive_dimensions.' - '.$this->archive_price.' inc P&P</span><br /><a href="basket.php?addprint='.$this->archive_id.'"><img src="images/shop/basket_button.png" border="0" /></a></center>';
```